# spring-integration-sftp v6 resets connection during idle time

Tags: spring-integration-sftp, apache-mina, apache-sshd

In spring-integration-sftp v6.1.2 under Java 17/Spring 6.1.2, the sftp sends many connections, outputs many warnings (presented unverified DSA key, SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600834/600000 ms, etc.) and throws exceptions (IOException: Connection reset) during idle time. what did I miss in building SessionFactory such as setTimeOut? Thanks

Coding:

```
   @Bean
    
        public SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> sftpSessionFactory() throws InvalidConfigException, IOException {
        
        
            SshClient sshClient = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
            sshClient.setKeyExchangeFactories(NamedFactory.setUpTransformedFactories(
                    false,
                    BuiltinDHFactories.VALUES,
                    ClientBuilder.DH2KEX
            ));
        
            boolean isAllowUnknownKeys = properties.isAllowUnknownKeys();
        
            sshClient.setSignatureFactories(new ArrayList<>(BuiltinSignatures.VALUES));
        
            ServerKeyVerifier serverKeyVerifier =
                    isAllowUnknownKeys ? AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier.INSTANCE : RejectAllServerKeyVerifier.INSTANCE;
        
            if (!isAllowUnknownKeys) {
                String knownHostFileStr = properties.getKnownHostFile();
                if (StringUtils.isBlank(knownHostFileStr))
                    throw new KnownHostFileNotDefinedException("Must define known_hosts file when allow-unknown-keys is false. ");
        
                File knownHostFile = new File(knownHostFileStr);
                if (!knownHostFile.exists())
                    throw new KnownHostFileNotFoundException("Cannot find known_hosts file when allow-unknown-keys is false.");
        
                Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("file:"+properties.getKnownHostFile());
                serverKeyVerifier = new ResourceKnownHostsServerKeyVerifier(resource);
            }
        
            sshClient.setServerKeyVerifier(serverKeyVerifier);
            sshClient.setPasswordIdentityProvider(PasswordIdentityProvider.wrapPasswords(properties.getPassword()));
        
            if (properties.getSshPrivateKey() != null) {
                if(!(new File(properties.getSshPrivateKey()).exists()))
                    throw new KnownHostFileNotDefinedException("Cannot find known_hosts file private key file. ");

                Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("file:"+properties.getSshPrivateKey());;
                logger.info("SFTP Configuration: privateKey - length {}", resource.contentLength());
     
                IoResource<Resource> privateKeyResource =
                        new AbstractIoResource<>(Resource.class, resource) {
        
                            @Override
                            public InputStream openInputStream() throws IOException {
                                return getResourceValue().getInputStream();
                            }
        
                        };
                try {
                    Collection<KeyPair> keys =
                            SecurityUtils.getKeyPairResourceParser()
                                    .loadKeyPairs(null, privateKeyResource,
                                            FilePasswordProvider.of(properties.getSshPrivatePassphrase()));
                    sshClient.setKeyIdentityProvider(KeyIdentityProvider.wrapKeyPairs(keys));
                }
                catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
                    throw new IOException("Cannot load private key: " + resource.getFilename(), ex);
                }
            }
        
            DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(sshClient, true);
        
            factory.setHost(properties.getHost());
            factory.setPort(properties.getPort());
            factory.setUser(properties.getUsername());
        
            return factory;
        }
```

Logging:

```
2024-02-07 01:54:31.028  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-02-07 01:54:31.036  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-02-07 01:54:31.037  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
2024-02-07 01:54:31.223  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-02-07 01:54:31.230  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3577 ms
2024-02-07 01:54:32.347  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] c.b.g.o.j.a.AccessAutoConfiguration      : Bootstraping Access Library
2024-02-07 01:54:32.348  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] c.b.g.o.j.a.AccessAutoConfiguration      : Input plugin: sftp
2024-02-07 01:54:32.349  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] c.b.g.o.j.a.AccessAutoConfiguration      : Output plugin: rabbitmq
2024-02-07 01:54:33.554  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] s.c.u.s.e.EdDSASecurityProviderRegistrar : getOrCreateProvider(EdDSA) created instance of net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSASecurityProvider
2024-02-07 01:54:33.928  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] c.b.g.o.j.a.p.sftp.AutoConfiguration     : InboundChannelAdapter started...
2024-02-07 01:54:34.730  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2024-02-07 01:54:35.055  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2024-02-07 01:54:35.055  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'jrcc-receiver.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2024-02-07 01:54:35.056  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2024-02-07 01:54:35.056  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {service-activator:handler.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'sftpChannel' channel
2024-02-07 01:54:35.057  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'jrcc-receiver.sftpChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2024-02-07 01:54:35.057  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'handler.serviceActivator'
2024-02-07 01:54:35.059  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started bean 'sftpMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter'
2024-02-07 01:54:35.131  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-02-07 01:54:35.143  INFO 1 --- [           main] [,] c.b.g.jrcc.receiver.ReceiverApplication  : Started ReceiverApplication in 8.41 seconds (process running for 10.222)
2024-02-07 01:54:40.012  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] [,] o.a.s.c.i.DefaultIoServiceFactoryFactory : No detected/configured IoServiceFactoryFactory; using Nio2ServiceFactoryFactory
2024-02-07 01:54:40.148  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:54:45.059  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:54:50.056  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:54:55.057  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:00.058  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:05.054  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:10.056  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:15.057  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:20.056  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:25.057  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:30.054  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:35.057  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:40.058  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:45.058  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:50.057  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:55.059  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 01:55:59.524  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] [,] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-02-07 01:55:59.525  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] [,] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-02-07 01:55:59.527  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] [,] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2024-02-07 01:55:59.636  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] [,] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq-cluster:5672
2024-02-07 01:55:59.732  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] [,] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: connectionFactory#53c68ce:0/SimpleConnection@5d1dbbe0 [delegate=amqp://rabbitmq@10.97.144.46:5672/, localPort=38744]
2024-02-07 03:22:31.010  INFO 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600830/600000 ms.
2024-02-07 03:22:35.052  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:22:36.199  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:22:40.060  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:22:41.010  INFO 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600830/600000 ms.
2024-02-07 03:22:41.846  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:22:45.053  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:22:45.682  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:22:50.052  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:22:50.235  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:22:55.052  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:22:56.010  INFO 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600834/600000 ms.
2024-02-07 03:23:00.061  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:23:00.122  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:23:01.010  INFO 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600825/600000 ms.
2024-02-07 03:23:02.059  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:23:05.051  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:23:06.010  INFO 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600844/600000 ms.
2024-02-07 03:23:10.051  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:23:12.558  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:23:15.055  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:23:17.271  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:23:20.053  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:23:25.055  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:23:25.116  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:23:30.054  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:23:31.805  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:23:35.051  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:23:35.882  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:23:36.010  INFO 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600838/600000 ms.
2024-02-07 03:23:40.052  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:23:41.489  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:23:45.056  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:23:46.127  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:23:50.056  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:23:55.055  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:00.058  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:00.575  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:24:05.054  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:10.056  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:11.369  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:24:15.053  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:20.050  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:20.962  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:24:21.010  INFO 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600837/600000 ms.
2024-02-07 03:24:25.055  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:30.050  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:35.058  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:35.123  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:24:40.058  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:43.486  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:24:45.052  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:46.776  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:24:50.052  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:50.717  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:24:51.010  INFO 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600836/600000 ms.
2024-02-07 03:24:55.006  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:24:55.051  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:24:56.010  INFO 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600836/600000 ms.
2024-02-07 03:25:00.060  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:25:01.644  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:25:05.048  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:25:05.996  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:25:10.052  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:25:11.010  INFO 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600837/600000 ms.
2024-02-07 03:25:15.053  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:25:20.051  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:25:23.619  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:25:25.060  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-2] [,] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22 presented unverified DSA key: SHA256:20q6x+yl2wYUlt7cFEqziDKLra8z9v12jTxFscOE7Uc
2024-02-07 03:25:25.306  WARN 1 --- []-nio2-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : exceptionCaught(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22])[state=Opened] IOException: Connection reset
2024-02-07 03:25:26.010  INFO 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] [,] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[sftpjrcc@sfeg.test.ag.ca/142.34.91.187:22]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600835/600000 ms.
```